# how can to_char with zero before number in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have database like below:

```
WITH TB AS(
     SELECT 1 NONB FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 89 NONB FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 193 NONB FROM DUAL  
)
SELECT * FROM TB
```

I want change column NONB `to_char(NONB)` and display zero before the number like below.

> 001
>
> 089
>
> 189

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Learn to google for, and then to read, the Oracle documentation for its functions. In this case: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34570

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lpad()`:

```
select lpad(nonb, 3, '0')
from tb;
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/LUIFD33786).

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
WITH TB AS(
     SELECT 1 NONB FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 89 NONB FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 193 NONB FROM DUAL  
)
 SELECT to_char(nonb, 'FM000') FROM TB
```